# creating multiple php arrays 

Tags: php

I have a html form with checkboxes.  Someone selects one or more checkboxes and hit the delete button then it will delete the files references out of the database and delete the files out of Amazon S3.  This is the code I used to find all the checkboxes

```
$checkbox_select = JRequest::getVar('checkboxselect', '', 'POST'); //just a Joomla way of doing a $_POST with extra security
var_dump($checkbox_select); //this returns: array(2) { ["video_1.mp4"]=> string(2) "on" ["video_2.mp4"]=> string(2) "on" ["video_3.mp4"]=> string(2) "on"} 

// Localize and sanitize each individual value
foreach (array_keys($checkbox_select) as $element) {
    $deleteNames[] = $db->quote($element);
}
var_dump($deleteNames); //array(3) { [0]=> string(13) "'video_3.mp4'" [1]=> string(13) "'video_2.mp4'" [2]=> string(13) "'video_1.mp4'" }
```

My problem is with Amazon S3 and multiple file deletion.  The format I need to put S3 deletion in is quite confusing:

```
$s3->delete_objects('mybucket', array(

'objects' => array( // accepts a *list* of one or more *hashes*

    // a *hash* that contains a "key" key with a value, and maybe a "version_id" key with a value
    array('key' => 'object (file) name'),

    // a second hash representing a file
    // a third hash representing a file
    // and so on...
),
));
```

As far as I understand (from S3 delete_objects function) the final associated array has `key` as the actual key value. With the last `var_dump` I've got all video names in an array now I just need to convert that array to a bunch of arrays in this format:

```
array ('key' => 'video_1.mp4'),
array ('key' => 'video_2.mp4'),
array ('key' => 'video_3.mp4'),
...and so on
```

How can I create these arrays?  Should I be using the first var_dump I have or the second (they both have the video file names listed)?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop over your array and create a new array in the desired format.

Example:

```
<?php

foreach (array_keys($checkbox_select) as $element) {
    $deleteNames[] = array('key' => $db->quote($element));
}
```

*Untested, may contain errors*

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [this post](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#61217) in the [php documentation for array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php). You'll get a brief idea of how to achieve it.